# Node getting added twice into list

Tags: python, function, class, nodes

This is my code ignore if any of the spacing is wrong the code works perfectly fine in python.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value  
        self.next = None 

    def __str__(self):
        return "Node({})".format(self.value)

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def setNext(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next

    def setValue(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value


    __repr__ = __str__



class OrderedLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None
        self.count = 0

    def __str__(self):
        temp=self.head
        out=[]
        while temp:
            out.append(str(temp.value))
            temp=temp.next
        out=' '.join(out)
        return ('Head:{}\nTail:{}\nList:{}'.format(self.head,self.tail,out))

    __repr__=__str__

    def add(self, value):
        #write your code here

        if self.head == None:
            new_node = Node(value)
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = self.head
            self.head.setNext(self.tail)


        if self.head.value > value:
            new_node = Node(value)
            new_node.value = value
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            self.tail.setNext(new_node)
            self.tail = new_node

        self.count += 1




    def pop(self):
        #write your code here
        if self.head == None:
            return 'List is empty'

        if len(self) == 1:
            value = self.head.getValue()
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
            self.count = 0
            return value

        current = self.head
        while current.next is not self.tail:
            current = current.getNext()

        value = self.tail.getValue()
        self.tail = current
        self.tail.next = None

        self.count -= 1
        return value






    def isEmpty(self):
        #write your code here
        return self.head == None

    def __len__(self):
        #write your code here
        return self.count
```

The only problem I have with it is that when I first use the function add it adds the number twice. Below is the outcome when I first call add every time after that it adds the number only once. How can I fix it so it only adds the first number once instead of twice.

```
>>> x=OrderedLinkedList()
>>> x.add(2)
>>> print(x)
Head:Node(2)
Tail:Node(2)
List:2 2
```

add(item) adds a new Node with value=item to the list making sure that the ascending order is preserved. It needs the item and returns nothing.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for contributing to SO. You might have more luck getting an answer if you work to reduce your problem to its simplest form. Look for the smallest possible amount of code you can provide that illustrates the problem you're having. Posting a big wall of code, some of which is unrelated to your issue, and asking the community to debug it for you is usually not likely to get a response. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it adds the first number twice since you need fix a bug in your `add` method by adding an `elif`:

```
def add(self, value):
   if self.head == None:
        new_node = Node(value)
        self.head = new_node
        self.tail = self.head
        # self.head.setNext(self.tail) ## remove to prevent infinity loop


    elif self.head.value > value:
        new_node = Node(value)
        new_node.value = value
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    else:
        new_node = Node(value)
        self.tail.setNext(new_node)
        self.tail = new_node
```

Since, if the head es `None` once the data is added then the next conditional always will execute one of the two parts on `if` or `else`.

Comment: I tried this but now when I try to do print(x) nothing prints out and actually won't let me type anything else after that like it gets stuck.. Is it causing another error?

Comment: Sure, looking at your first `if`, you need to remove the code `self.head.setNext(self.tail)` it is causing you while at print is getting loop infinity.

Comment: Thank you a lot! If you don't mind can you explain why its causing an infinite loop inside the if statement?

Comment: Sure, it is falling in an infinity loop due the folloing: 1. you create the node setting `next` to `None`, but after you perform the assignation to `head` and `tail` both points to the same node, then when you perform the `head.setNext` you are making it to reference the same element making you list a cycled list.